Route local traffic using VPC Connector
I have a Cloud Function configured to route all its egress traffic using a VPC Serverless Connector, which has a static IP assigned. The Cloud Function connects to a SFTP server which has this static IP whitelisted.
I'm not able to execute my python code locally, because the connection would be rejected by the SFTP firewall. Could I execute the python script locally, and route the traffic through that same VPC Serverles Connector somehow? I don't know if it's possible to do this using few infrastructure provisioning, or I would need to create a VM and start a IAP tunnel for this

Create a Compute Engine VM within the same VPC network and modify the Cloud Function's Ingress and Egress settings to allow All (public) traffic the set up Cloud VPN and configure Private Google Access to connect from on-prem to the VPC.
